# Mysql transaction with table locking

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, table-locking

I need to use table locking (write) and along with that update a few tables, so I need transactions at the same time, as the locking is not transaction-safe.

From mysql documentation I read the following
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html

> The correct way to use LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES with
>   transactional tables, such as InnoDB tables, is to begin a transaction
>   with SET autocommit = 0 (not START TRANSACTION) followed by LOCK
>   TABLES, and to not call UNLOCK TABLES until you commit the transaction
>   explicitly. For example, if you need to write to table t1 and read
>   from table t2, you can do this:
>
> ```
> SET autocommit=0;
> LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 READ, ...;
> ... do something with tables t1 and t2 here ...
> COMMIT;
> UNLOCK TABLES;
> ```
>
> When you call LOCK TABLES, InnoDB internally takes its own table lock,
>   and MySQL takes its own table lock. InnoDB releases its internal table
>   lock at the next commit, but for MySQL to release its table lock, you
>   have to call UNLOCK TABLES. You should not have autocommit = 1,
>   because then InnoDB releases its internal table lock immediately after
>   the call of LOCK TABLES, and deadlocks can very easily happen. InnoDB
>   does not acquire the internal table lock at all if autocommit = 1, to
>   help old applications avoid unnecessary deadlocks.

On the other hand from this page we have
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html

> To disable autocommit mode implicitly for a single series of
>   statements, use the START TRANSACTION statement:
>
> ```
> START TRANSACTION;
> SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
> UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
> COMMIT;
> ```
>
> With START TRANSACTION, autocommit remains disabled until you end the
>   transaction with COMMIT or ROLLBACK. The autocommit mode then reverts
>   to its previous state.

So, if with `START TRANSACTION` disables the autocommit, then why in table locking section it says that the correct way is `to begin a transaction with SET autocommit = 0 (not START TRANSACTION)`. Am I missing something or there is a contradiction between these two ? Can I use `START TRANSACTION` with table locking? I am using InnoDB.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you feel you need to use table locks? Why is row locking not sufficient?

Comment: multiple scripts should work in parallel, and `select for update` is not ok, (i guess u meant that), because they should make select, update and insert,  so the entire table should be locked, so the scripts will work synchronously

Answer (score 3):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html

> - LOCK TABLES is not transaction-safe and implicitly commits any active transaction before attempting to lock the tables.
> - Beginning a transaction (for example, with START TRANSACTION) implicitly commits any current transaction and **releases existing table locks**.

Answer (score 0):

This case on Maria DB. . No commits were used.
A lock seems to end the transaction so all changes are applied.
Not sure if  during the "no updated" scenario's the tables stay locked from others queries to read the data.

```
Start
Lock
Change
Rollback
Unlock
-------------
updated records

Start
Lock
Change
Unlock
Rollback
-------------
updated records

Lock
Start
Change
Rollback
Unlock
----------------
no updated records

Lock
start
Change
Unlock
Rollback
-------------
no updated records

Start
Change
Rollback
-------------
no updated records
```